# remove for avoiding recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have been reading "Javascript:Definitive Guid" one example puzzled me. Why the code taking care of IE need to "this.onpropertychange = null" to avoid recursion. How will the recursion occur? And why we don't need to treat function "upcase" which deals with other browsers the same way? Thank you.

```
//Example 17-7. Using the propertychange event to detect text input
function forceToUpperCase(element) {
    if (typeof element === "string") element = document.getElementById(element);
    element.oninput = upcase;
    element.onpropertychange = upcaseOnPropertyChange;
    // Easy case: the handler for the input event
    function upcase(event) {
        this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    }
    // Hard case: the handler for the propertychange event
    function upcaseOnPropertyChange(event) {
        var e = event || window.event;
        // If the value property changed
        if (e.propertyName === "value") {
            // Remove onpropertychange handler to avoid recursion
            this.onpropertychange = null;
            // Change the value to all uppercase
            this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
            // And restore the original propertychange handler
            this.onpropertychange = upcaseOnPropertyChange;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what `onpropertychange` does?

Comment: no, I cannot find reference for IE's event object properties. Could you elaborate it? Also, there is a "propertyName". I guess this is also IE specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when the event handler changes the "value" property, it'll trigger *another* "propertychange" event. Thus, as soon as the first event handler finishes, the browser would immediately call it again.

(It's not really "recursion" in this case, it'd just be an infinite loop.)

The first "simple" handler is responding to "input" events, and updating the "value" property won't trigger one of those. It will, however, trigger a "propertychange" event, so it wouldn't hurt to do the same thing in that handler too.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, I think I got it.